# swift 2 conversion help - 89 issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7

So I just finished up my first app built with swift 1.2 and made for ios 8. It successfully reached the app store last week, but now the time has come for me to update the code for ios 9 and swift 2.

The previous app worked perfectly with no issues, no crashes, but opening the exact same project in xcode 7 throws me 89 issues. I've gone through the process where xcode will automatically convert it for me, but still leaves issues. I've gotten it to a point where all build issues were gone, but the app does not function. I haven't been able to even get past my login screen as tapping the input fields to enter a user name and password wont even register my touch and let my type.

It's very frustrating going from spending a lot of time making a functioning app, only to have it completely not work now.

Does anyone have good recommendations on how I can work my way though this and get my app back to where it works again but for ios9 and swift 2? Should I let Xcode convert it for me and work from there? Should I convert myself? Any help would be awesome as I'm still new to all of this. Just when I thought I was figuring some of this out, it all changes and breaks.

Some example errors I'm getting if this helps:

- a lot of issues about options not being unwrapped. I can fix those I think.

-This tells me "Downcast from 'CLLocation?' to 'CLLocation' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?"   not sure what to do here.

```
    let locationUpdated = locations.last as! CLLocation
```

-variable currentUser was written to but never read

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
```

- Immutable value 'activeFieldPresent' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it. get this error a lot with other immutable values. what does this mean and how can I fix it? Is this why my taps to type arent working?

  ```
  func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
  {
  //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
  self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
  let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
  let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
  let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

  self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
  self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

  var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
  aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
  if let activeFieldPresent = activeField   // Heres where the error shows
  {
      if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin))
      {
          self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField!.frame, animated: true)
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you do not use the converter and work through the errors on your own, trying to understand the syntax changes from Swift 1.2 -> Swift 2.0.  Here are a few changes, relevant to the specific errors you've noted above.

1. As part of iOS 9, Apple has added generic support to Objective-C.  What this means is that there are a lot of places where you used to have to cast something coming from an `NSArray` to a type to avoid getting `AnyObject` where you no longer have to.

For example, the `locations` variable you're using above used to be an array of `AnyObject` and is now an array of `CLLocation`. So you'll need to change this code:

```
let locationUpdated = locations.last as! CLLocation
```

to this:

```
let locationUpdated = locations.last!
```

2. The compiler has also gotten better at warning you when you create a variable that you don't use.  If it's telling you a variable was written to but never read, that's exactly what it means.  You're not using that variable anywhere and can take it out.  In your last code example, you should be using `activeFieldPresent` in the body of your `if let` statement instead of `activeField!`.  Once you do that, the warning about not using it will go away.

Comment: thanks will do. another question, I built the new version of the app on my device for the first time, and entering text in the fields works great on the device, but not in the simulator. So maybe thats just a bug in the simulator and hopefully not an issue with my code?

Comment: I don't seem to have any problems entering text in the simulator on my apps.  Generally I lean towards such things being a bug in the code (not to say there is never an issue with the SDK).

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2 many properties are declared more specific than `AnyObject` in Swift 1.

For example `locations` is declared as `[CLLocation]` so there is no need anymore to downcast it. But you might have to unwrap `last` because it's an optional.

*Immutable value … was never used* is a warning, not an error. It remembers you that the variable `activeFieldPresent` is never used and could be replaced by the `_` (don't care) placeholder

Answer (score 0):

As an example your code

```
if let activeFieldPresent = activeField   // Heres where the error shows
{
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin))
    {
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField!.frame, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The compiler assumes that if you do something pointless, then it is probably a mistake on your side. activeFieldPresent is never used, so the let is rather pointless. You could have just written "if activeField != nil". Better would have been

```
if let activeFieldPresent = activeField
{
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeFieldPresent.frame.origin))
    {
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeFieldPresent.frame, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The "if let" not only checks that an optional is not nil, it also gives you the unwrapped value. So why wouldn't you use it? (A better variable name might be useful).